# How do you prevent the dock from jumping between monitors in macOS without unchecking the "Displays have separate Spaces" option in multidisplay rig?

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors

I have a multimonitor setup.

By default the `Displays have separate Spaces` settign is checked in MacOS, and it causes the dock to hop between monitors if you hover your mouse at the bottom of any of your monitors even unintentionally, which is extremely annoying and frustrating because it causes apps to contract to make space for the dock, and when the dock hops away to another monitor again the apps on the previous monitor to not expand back - so the amount of usable space in the apps is constantly reduced by this constant dock hopping (which is annoying in and of itself).

This solution to disable dock hopping:

> Go to System Preferences > Mission Control, then deselect the option
> "Displays have separate Spaces"

...is not acceptable because then I cannot have full-screen video on one monitor and a note-taking application on my other monitor - switching a video to full-screen causes other monitors to go dark when `Displays have separate Spaces` is unchecked.

How do I disable dock hopping between my monitors without making all of my screens go dark when I switch one of the windows to the full-screen mode?

If there is no native way to do it, kindly share a 3rd party utility that would allow me to do that.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458039/how-do-you-prevent-the-dock-from-jumping-between-monitors-in-macos-without-unche

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found any solutions to permanently lock the Dock to a single screen in macOS. But you can set the `autohide-delay` user defaults to a larger value which also affects the time it takes for the Dock to move screens.

Command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 9999999
```

The value is in seconds. I've set mine to 5 seconds so I can always move it intentionally if I want to, but this gets rid of the unintentional moves.

It's also worth noting that this value seems to be ignored by the OS in some configurations. I've noticed the behavior is slightly different e.g. when you have screens arranged in a vertical setup on top of each other.

Found originally in [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/us743j/comment/jjih1tk/).

Answer (score -3):

A solution has been offered here: https://www.idownloadblog.com/2020/01/15/how-to-lock-the-dock-on-mac/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1210609)

Comment: As a side note: the information in that link doesn't actually solves the issue. The dock will still jump around _between_ screens.